# Friends email-id's from Google+ iOS SDK

Tags: google-plus

I am getting a NSArray containing GTLPlusPerson type objects. It contains their display names, urls, image, objectType, id, and eTag. But it dosen't contain their email-id's. I need to get their Emails. Is there any way to do so?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This isn't a programming question, it's a question about a 3rd party service and it's offered capabilities / documentation.

Comment: @Wain It may not be a computer science question - or a question about programming language syntax - but it's just as valid on stack overflow as a question about the .net framework etc. there are a bunch of questions about Google APIs on SO. It's a perfectly valid question for the site.

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:**

You can't.

**Longer answer:**

It takes special consent to get a user's email address. Specifically, if you want the email address of the user logging in, you must request the `userinfo.email` scope (or any scopes that imply this one) - at which point the user will be specifically asked if they want to give you their email address.

Users do not have the ability to consent to this disclosure on behalf of people in their circles.

This makes sense when you consider the fact that email addresses aren't public in G+, and that anyone can add anyone else to their circles without permission. As a G+ user, I do not have access to the email addresses of everyone in my circles. Therefore, your app can't get it either, just because I logged into it with my G+ account.